# Change the delay before the Taskbar expands

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, delay

I like to keep my Taskbar collapsed on my laptop.  Unfortunately, this plus the lack of precision control that the touchpad brings, I am constantly accidentally expanding the taskbar.

What I'd like is to lengthen the delay time between when the cursor nears the taskbar and when it expands.

Extra points for controlling the behavior differently for mouse input and for touch input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the new Aero preview features? Where when you hover over an icon it shows a preview? You can control that by modifying the registry. The location that holds this control is:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

The "ExtendedUIHoverTime" DWORD is the time in milliseconds to wait when a mouse hover is detected to show the Aero preview ([source](http://damnmachine.com/309/windows-7-taskbar-reg-tweaks.html)).

The problem with input devices is that they all detect as a mouse pointer. Windows doesn't differentiate between a touchpad and a physical mouse. The only way I can think to change behavior when you plug in a mouse is to create a script that toggles the registry value. It's a clunky way to do it and I think it would be better to compromise on a time that fits in both situations.

Hope this helps

Comment: Wish it did, but no.  You can configure the taskbar to hide.  When your mouse gets near it, it expands.  I'm looking to have it wait a half sec before expanding, instead of opening immediately.  It seems to interpret a swipe by a finger as different from a mouse hover; I'd love to keep that yet have it wait if the cursor butted against the edge.  A fine line, but one that could be distinguished.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this software

http://pmdevigne.free.fr/ActiveTache.html

As kindly answered by this friendly user @vctls
https://superuser.com/a/1331970/290789