# Windows 10 task bar hide immediately

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I'm running Windows 10 and I was wondering if anyone knew how to change the task bar so that it hides as quickly as it un-hides. When I hover my mouse to the area to make it pop out to starts and completes really quickly, but when I move my mouse away to let it hide again there is a slight delay and if I overshot and just want to press a button near the edge of the screen it means I have to wait.

I know on my Mac I can adjust a .plist file to adjust various settings. Is there a similar approach for Windows 10.

Thanks guys and gals

Comment: I dont think it is possbile because that will be a problem if you want to click something on the taskbat area:  i.e. you want to click it,  but the taskbar immediately come up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Instantly taskbar when auto-hide on - windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/221123/show-instantly-taskbar-when-auto-hide-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 24):

I tried the solution I [read here earlier](https://superuser.com/a/1331970/855707) and it worked but it also disables the dragging effect of windows, so instead of dragging the window you will see a rectangle of the window size. I found this not very likable. And I found a better solution.

- go to Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced (tab) > Performance Settings... > Visual Effects (tab)
- Uncheck Fade or slide menus into view
- Apply changes

This will also auto-hide the taskbar and not introduce the dragging rectangle.

Comment: This is Q&A site, not a forum. Answers have no fixed order (every user can sort them in few ways). That's why the phrase "the above solution" has no exact meaning. For now there is only one other answer, therefore it's easy to understand what you mean; but more answers may still appear. In general it's best to refer to another answer with a link, e.g. "I tried the solution from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1049081/432690) and…". I encourage you to edit your answer and introduce such a link.

Answer (score 6):

Disabling the hiding/showing animation for speed-up the hiding of the taskbar (same for when showing it), will make the taskbar hide and/or show quickly, for achieve that:

1. Open the system information window by right-clicking the This computer icon (in your desktop) and choose Properties.

   In the left side, look for "Advanced System Settings".

   [image]

   Go to Performance (Settings) and then in the Visual effects tab disable the option "Show the window content while dragging".
   [image]

And that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Go to start menu and search for "advanced system settings".
Then simply uncheck this checkbox below,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** To remove ALL delay, if you don't mind installing something:

1. Disable "fade or slide into view" as explained in [this previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1279493).
2. Install [TaskbarActivate](http://pmdevigne.free.fr/TaskbarActivate.html).
3. Disable "delayed activation" in the settings, like this:
   [image: Taskbar Activate Settings]

Disabling animations doesn't remove all delay. The taskbar shows up more or less instantly but stays up for like half a second when you move your cursor out.
There might be a way of changing this through the registry, but I couldn't find one.
Amazingly, this little free software from last century still works in Windows 10.
(Not sure if this is a good or a bad sign for Windows Explorer…)

Comment: does this work with hiding?

Comment: it kinda works. it has to run to work though. id rather edit registry

Comment: I'm not comfortable installing any closed-source software last updated in 2003 which has the power to change OS behaviour - sounds like a security nightmare.

Comment: not necessary to install something if can be achieved simply in Windows itself.

Comment: No it can't. And that's why I wrote “ ALL delay, if you don't mind installing something” to begin with, and you'll note this answer still requires you to disable animations through the usual Windows settings anyway.
But disabling animations still leaves a little delay on hiding. I did try registry tweaks and they didn't remove the delay.